# eBay API getProductMetadataForCategories returns always The specified category ID is invalid

Tags: api, ebay-api

I'm trying to access Ebay Attributes for certain categories through API. It was functioning till certain time. Now whenever I try to use getProductMetadataForCategories, it returns Error 75040 The specified category ID is invalid.

I've found here another similar question and there was suggested that this category was remapped.
So I called GetCategoryMappings and GetCategories requests. In GetCategoryMappings response my category is not mentioned, but in GetCategories and it is not a parent category.

I've tried several categories and all of them returns same error.

Web Service URI:

> https://api.ebay.com/commerce/catalog/v1_beta/get_product_metadata_for_categories?primary_category_id=86207

HTTP Headers:

```
Authorization:Bearer token_deleted
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
Accept-Encoding:application/gzip
X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID:EBAY_DE
```

Response Headers:

```
content-length:183
content-encoding:gzip
date:Fri, 06 Mar 2020 13:36:44 GMT
nncoection:close
rlogid:t6%60drfojafsl%3C%3Dpiedbqgklbgwj%284%3E3233%3B%2Busqdrrp%2Buk%60%2Bceb%7C%28dlh-170b01002a6-0x133
set-cookie:ebay=%5Esbf%3D%23%5E;Domain=.ebay.com;Path=/
x-ebay-c-request-id:ri=PatSZo8I2Ubk,rci=573f635c2025eb59
x-ebay-c-version:1.0.0
x-ebay-client-tls-version:771, 10.218.89.196
x-ebay-esb-upstream:catalogapi.vip.ebay.com
x-ebay-request-id:170b0100290.a9c4361.571a5.eed858bf!/commerce/catalog/v1_beta/get_product_metadata!10.156.67.97!esbnewesbngcos[]!get_product_metadata_for_categories!slccatalogapi-2907548.stratus.slc.ebay.com!r1catalogapi[ShieldClient[!Ginger.ngrlsvc.v1.POST!slcngrlsvc-3525110.stratus.slc.ebay.com!r1ngrlsvc[]]!SdarsClient[!sdars.v2!slcsdars4-3319875.stratus.slc.ebay.com!r1sdars4[]]]
x-ebay-svc-ep-cookielet:321=0001583501804197
x-ebay-svc-tracking-data:<a>ul=de-DE&uc=77&bs=77&nqt=AA**&!_epec=7,6,8&nqc=AA**</a>
content-type:application/json
connection:keep-alive
strict-transport-security:max-age=31536000
```

Response Body:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorId": 75040,
      "domain": "API_CATALOG",
      "category": "REQUEST",
      "message": "The specified category ID is invalid.",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "fieldName",
          "value": "primary_category_id"
        },
        {
          "name": "fieldValue",
          "value": "86207"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no ideas why it always returns the error.

Has eBay changed something in API calls?
Has anybody seen something similar last days?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is eBay's, not yours.

The [documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/catalog/resources/product_metadata/methods/getProductMetadataForCategories) suggests `https://api.ebay.com/commerce/catalog/v1_beta/get_product_metadata_for_categories?primary_category_id=500&other_applicable_category_ids=34,36,63` but it returns exactly the same error.

Sorry.